# How to make contrast with image and white text in react-native

Tags: react-native

I'm struggling with this problem: I've an image with some white icons on it and also some texts.

[image]

This is an example, as you can see it is very hard to read the "2.1k" and even to see the icons!

This is an example from Instagram:

[image]

As you can see, the icons are clearly visible and also the text is clearly visible.

Now, how can I obtain that in the first image? Is it like an overlay? This is the actual code for the three icons in my image:

```js
<View style={{position: "absolute", bottom: 0, width: "100%", left: 0, padding: 10, paddingLeft: 20, flex: 1, maxHeight: 100, flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center", height: "100%", shadowColor: "gray", shadowOpacity: 1, shadowOffset: {width: 0, height: 12}, shadowRadius: 16.00, elevation: 24}}>
        <View>
            <Pressable>
                <AntDesign name="hearto" color={"white"} size={25} /> 
            </Pressable>
            <Text style={{marginTop: 2, fontFamily: "Roboto", fontWeight: "bold", color: "white"}}>
                2.1k
            </Text>
        </View>

        <View style={{marginLeft: 35}}>
            <Pressable>
                <Ionicons name="chatbubbles-outline" color={"white"} size={25} /> 
            </Pressable>
            <Text style={{marginTop: 2, fontFamily: "Roboto", fontWeight: "bold", color: "white"}}>
                2.1k
            </Text>
        </View>

        <View style={{marginLeft: 35}}>
            <Pressable>
                <AntDesign name="sharealt" color={"white"} size={25} style={{}} /> 
            </Pressable>
            <Text style={{marginTop: 2, fontFamily: "Roboto", fontWeight: "bold", color: "white"}}>
                2.1k
            </Text>
        </View>
</View>
```

Any advice will be appreciated, thank you! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried adding a subtle drop shadow to both Icons & Text :

```js
<View style={{...}}>
    <View>
        <Pressable>
            <AntDesign name="hearto" color={"white"} size={25} style={styles.iconShadow} />
        </Pressable>
        <Text style={styles.text}>
            2.1k
        </Text>
    </View>

    <View style={{ marginLeft: 35 }}>
        <Pressable>
            <Ionicons name="chatbubbles-outline" color={"white"} size={25} style={styles.iconShadow} />
        </Pressable>
        <Text style={styles.text}>
            2.1k
        </Text>
    </View>

    <View style={{ marginLeft: 35 }}>
        <Pressable>
            <AntDesign name="sharealt" color={"white"} size={25} style={styles.iconShadow} />
        </Pressable>
        <Text style={styles.text}>
            2.1k
        </Text>
    </View>
</View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    text: {
        textShadowOffset: {
            width: 2, height: 2
        },
        textShadowRadius: 10,
        textShadowColor: '#333',

        marginTop: 2,
        fontFamily: "Roboto",
        fontWeight: "bold",
        color: "white"
    }, 
    iconShadow: {
        textShadowOffset: {
            width: 2, height: 2
        },
        textShadowRadius: 15,
        textShadowColor: '#333'
    }

})
```

you can play with values until you are satisfied